# Educause Security Professionals 2012 Meetup

Tags: discussion, conference

Much like what Jeff is doing for DEFCON, let us in the education realm get together for our event.

I propose the evening of Wednesday May 16th. Depending on attendance, I may even buy a round.

Who's in, and who knows the area to say where to go?

Comment: I support this, despite being 3752 miles away!